# How to format date time string from python in to NodeJS UI

Tags: javascript, python, sql, node.js, python-2.x

I have my UI in written NodeJS. There is a column called 'opened' which specifies the date and time an issue was opened. The format of this is a String. I want to be able to format this in the current format which it is in ' 2019-01-26|12:34:09' in to the format ' Wed Jan 26 2019 12:34:09.

My backend a RESTAPI written in python. There is function which convert the issue in to json.

```
def _issue_to_json(issue):
    return {
        'id': issue.id,
        'title': issue.title,
        'description': issue.description,
        'opened': issue.opened.isoformat("|") if issue.opened else None,
        'closed': issue.closed.isoformat("|") if issue.closed else None,
    }
```

My SQL script is also used in order to store each issue in to the sqlite3 database:

```
CREATE TABLE issues(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  opened_datetime CHAR(26) DEFAULT (datetime('now')),
  closed_datetime CHAR(26) DEFAULT (datetime('now'))
)
```

My UI index.js is as follows :

```
const m = require('mithril')

class IssuesList {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.model = vnode.attrs.model
  }
  oninit() {
    this.model.loadIssues()

  }
  view() {

    return m('table.table', [

      m('thead', [
        m('th', 'title'),
        m('th', 'opened'),
        m('th', 'closed')

      ]),
      m('tbody', [

        this.model.list.map(item =>

          m('tr', [
            m('td.title-cell', m("a", {href: `/issues/${item.id}`, oncreate: m.route.link}, item.title)),
            m('td.opened-cell', item.opened ,
            m('td.closed-cell', item.closed))
          ])
        )
      ])
    ])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class. You can use it to convert a date string into a `Date` object, for instance:

```
var date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
```

You should use ISO 8601 date format, do not replace the "T" with "|" in Python:

```py
def _issue_to_json(issue):
    return {
        'id': issue.id,
        'title': issue.title,
        'description': issue.description,
        'opened': issue.opened.isoformat() if issue.opened else None,
        'closed': issue.closed.isoformat() if issue.closed else None,
    }
```

Comment: The date and time already set in item.opened. I tried doing the following but everything disappeared :

 m('td.opened-cell', new Date(item.opened) ,

Comment: Have you dropped the "|"? Any error log in your console?

Comment: No error log from my console. It prints the date as follows "2019-01-26T16:28:29".